# How to simulate an AC line filter in LT Spice

Tags: filter, spice, line

I'm fairly new to LT spice and am trying to simulate an AC line filter, but it keeps giving me the error K1: coupling to shorted out (ignored) inductor L1. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the circuit:

[image: Schematic]

Comment: L1 is shorted on your schematic, you have net "BRN" as input and output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try a small resistor in series with each of L1 and L2 - I use microcap and similar things happen with coupled inductors. Maybe also try a 0.001 ohm resistor in series with V1 too. I don't see anything in particular that would cause a voltage discrepancy but sometimes you have to help the math engines work things out more cleanly with the odd small resistor added.

Maybe you should choose a non-unity coupling coefficient too - try 0.99 (you may have done this of course already)

Answer (score 0):

You have to define LINK FACTOR AS     K1 L1 L2 1